# How to select a tray on a printer thorugh code when printing from a word document in VB (VS2019)

Tags: vba, printing

Hi I'm trying to create a word document and then print it with VB in visual studio 2019. 
Creation works ok, the document saves fine, and prints fine to the general tray but I cannot get the application to send the print job to a specified tray. the prints will just come out of the default paper try

the customers have an array of different printer makes and models

ive tried printing the document through word, ive also tried changing the printer itself on the computer to set the tray then change it back after

TRY 1

Dim intTray As Integer = varibleNumber

```
  If intTray = 1 Then

     oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterUpperBin
     oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterUpperBin

ElseIf intTray = 2 Then

     oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterMiddleBin
     oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterMiddleBin

ElseIf intTray = 3 Then

     oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterLowerBin
     oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterLowerBin

Else
    'else print default tray
     oWord.ActiveDocument.p.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterDefaultBin
     oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterDefaultBin
End If
```

TRY 2

```
Dim intTray As Integer = varibleNumber

Dim oPS As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings


If intTray = 1 Then

   oPS.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = oPS.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Item("Tray 1")
   oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = "Tray 1"
   oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = "Tray 1"

ElseIf intTray = 2 Then

   oPS.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = oPS.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Item("Tray 2")
   oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = "Tray 2"
   oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = "Tray 2"

ElseIf intTray = 3 Then

   oPS.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = oPS.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Item("Tray 3")
    oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = "Tray 3"
    oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = "Tray 3"

Else

   'else print default tray
    oPS.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = oPS.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PaperSources.Item("Automatically Select")

End If


modPrint.printWordDoc(oWord)
```

Pages just come out of the main printer tray.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue finally :) each printer has its own tray numbers for every tray, even if they are labelled Tray1 Tray2 etc.

so had to look through the papersources find when the source name equalled the tray number I wanted then grab the rawkind value of that source and use that as the tray number when allocating to the word firstpagetray

```
Dim intTray As Integer = <tray number i'm looking for>
Dim oPS As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
Dim paper_Source As PaperSource = New PaperSource
Dim i As Integer = 0

For Each ps As PaperSource In oPS.PaperSources

    If ps.SourceName.Contains(intTray.ToString) Then
        i = ps.RawKind
        Exit For
    End If

Next

oWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = i
```

Hope this helps others with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution that pops to my mind is to use VBA `Printer Setup Dialog` to change the `Tray` on your printer **settings**. Try executing this line of code and change the options on the printer you're using:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
```

### Edit:

Try using this code specific to `VB` framework. It's a valid starting point, since it allows you to select which print to use:

```
Public Sub Printing(printer As String)
    Try
        streamToPrint = New StreamReader(filePath)
        Try
            printFont = New Font("Arial", 10)
            Dim pd As New PrintDocument()
            AddHandler pd.PrintPage, AddressOf pd_PrintPage
            ' Specify the printer to use.
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer

            If pd.PrinterSettings.IsValid then
               pd.Print()
            Else
               MessageBox.Show("Printer is invalid.")
            End If
        Finally
            streamToPrint.Close()
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

You can find more info here on [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printername?view=netframework-4.8).

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey louis thanks for the reply. that would be ideal indeed, I forgot to include the client uses this software to kick out hundreds of these at a time so wants it to "just do it" rather than have a user click between each print

Comment: Hi, from what I've seen on my Excel, it remembers the choice you made. So it should be a "one-time configuration".

Comment: ah fab I shall have a look at this, im at my wits end :) thanks very much ill let you know if it works

Comment: hey louis afraid that didn't work VB doesn't seem to have that class, maybe that's just VBA

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that it didn't work. Check the update answer, and let me know if it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my comment that you MUST use the "rawkind" attribute of the tray number for this to work .. not what you think the tray number is when you list out the available trays

the "raw kind" number of the tray ID is what you must pass

Answer (score 0):

There's an app [www.trayselector.com](http://www.trayselector.com) which does exactly what you need.